# Why don't I get any output when I run my code (in Eclipse)?

Tags: java

Eclipse isn't showing that I'm doing anything wrong but when I hit run, its console just flashes and stays blank.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I commented most of the code but if you're having trouble trying to figure out what I was doing:

- A computer player and user roll a dice. Both dice rolls are random numbers from 1 to 6.
- There are 10 rounds. Whoever wins a round gets a point.
- At the end all points are added together and a winner is declared.

```
import java.util.Random; // Imports RNG

public class Guarascio_Chap_4_21 {

    // Calls for main
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create Random Object to create random numbers
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        // List of variables
        int number;
        int compPlayer;
        int userPlayer;
        int compScore = 0;
        int userScore = 0;
        int numRolls = 10;

        // For loop that begins at 1 and counts by 1 until it completes numRolls
        for (number = 1; number >= numRolls; number++)
        {

            // CompPlayer rolls the dice, then prints the number
            compPlayer = randomNumbers.nextInt(7)+1;
            System.out.println("Computer rolls a "+ compPlayer);

            // UserPlayer rolls the dice, then prints the number
            userPlayer = randomNumbers.nextInt(7)+1;
            System.out.println("User rolls a "+ userPlayer);

            // If/Else loop that informs the user which player has won the roll, 1 point is added to winners score 
            if (compPlayer > userPlayer)
            {
                compScore = (compScore + 1);
                System.out.println("Computer gains 1 point");
            }


            else
            {
                userScore = (userScore + 1);
                System.out.println("User gains 1 point");
            }

            // Print out both users and comps score
            System.out.println("Computers score is " + compScore);
            System.out.println("Users score is " + userScore);


            // Compare scores to decide winner
            if (compScore > userScore)
            {
                System.out.println("Computer wins with " + compScore + " points!");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("User wins with " + userScore + " points!");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Few things to note. Make sure to tag your question correctly. This is Java code and should be  tagged as such, ___not___ javascript. (I made a correspondig edit already). I also flagged your question as a _typo_ as it really looks like a typo to me rather than an actual problem in which other users will be interested or consider as helpful ;) You may also choose to delete your question if you agree with me that it was just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition `number >= numRolls` in your for-loop `for (number = 1; number >= numRolls; number++)` is ***always false***.

Change it to `number <= numRolls` to execute your loop and get your output in the console.